# how to load an xmodmap configuration file using .xinitrc

Tags: xmodmap, startx, xinit

I am trying to figure out how to use my .xinitrc file to load an xmodmap configuration file. Although this seems to be a popular problem around the internet, I can't seem to get it working. I am running Arch Linux and am using Gnome as my desktop environment. Initially, all that was in my .xinitrc file was `exec gnome-session`. I have tried putting the xmodmap command (which works if I manually run it in a terminal) before and after the gnome-session command:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
exec gnome-session
```

and

```
exec gnome-session
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

but neither worked. As suggested elsewhere on the internet, I also tried doing this with a sleep before the xmodmap command:

```
sleep 20 && xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
exec gnome-session
```

and

```
exec gnome-session
sleep 20 && xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

but neither worked.

Comment: Please paste the output of `pacman -Q xorg-xmodmap`  `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`.

Comment: @jasonwryan First command output: `xorg-xmodmap 1.0.9-2`, second command enabled unit files: `autovt@.service`, `getty@.service`, `netctl@myWifNetwork.service`, `remote-fs.target`

Comment: Please read the xinitrc wiki article and ensure that you source the correct scripts at the start of the file. Then use your first example above.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, I hadn't followed that page. But even after making those changes, my first example didn't work. I believe `exec gnome-session` or something else is resetting my keyboard layout. I've posted an answer to my own question which uses the sleep command (a bit inelegant, but the best I can do at this point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got this working was to put an `&` after the sleep/xmodmap command (i.e. running it in the background), and put the full command before gnome-session (and the sleep command was necessary):

```
sleep 20 && xmodmap ~/.xmodmap &
exec gnome-session
```

I believe `exec gnome-session` or something else is resetting my keyboard layout.